# Hebrew chars from pdf file shows gibberish using PHP

Tags: php, utf-8, file-get-contents, hebrew

I'm trying to get text from a pdf file with Hebrew in it and manipulate it, but when I'm using echo it shows these letters instead of Hebrew:

*ÇoÌ¬mÀÃ6ÜÍzWÃýCW¶°ÐÞ]Aµ±¸¤:ÄÞ[JÞaCå+wÎ[n6GZù>"âÊù+ýÕ9^6ÓF½íoßEcì¸_pùnÚbïjÅÅß^UtýÝ-®»þgåÄ¿Ù»Æ·8Ô¯Î²zÅr*

I made sure the page is in utf-8 and converted the returned text to utf-8 but it doesn't fix it.

When The text wasn't in utf-8 it showed these symbols:

��G�W����/��<� ������%�M����>*����z.�m47�M �O�4�Nf�/7ʓ쓻#2FGj��,U8�J*

I feel like I'm just missing something.

This is my code:

```
<?php

header('Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');

$formReturn = $_POST["formReturn"];

if ($formReturn)
{
    $file = $_FILES["gradesPdf"]["tmp_name"];
    $text = file_get_contents($file);
    $text = utf8_encode($text);
}

$html = '
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="he">
    
        <meta charset="utf-8" />

        <head>
        <title>נסיון</title>
        </head>
        
        <body>
        <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
            <input type="file" name="gradesPdf" id="gradesPdf">
            <br><br>
            <button type="submit">run</button>
            
            <input type="hidden" name="formReturn" value="1">
        </form>
        
        '. $text .'
                
        </body>
 
    </html>

';

echo $html;
```

Btw I can't use pdfParser, I tried the demo on their site and it didn't return the text the way I wanted. I think since my pdf has a table in it.

Comment: 1. PDF files are not simple formats, you cannot simply interpret their contents as text. You will need to use a library such as [spatie/pdf-to-text](https://packagist.org/packages/spatie/pdf-to-text), but YMMV as PDFs tend to be closer to image files than they are to text files. Ideally you would be looking to access the data in a form _prior_ to being turned into a PDF.

Comment: 2. Do not use `utf8_encode()` or `utf8_decode()` as they are badly-named, only convert between ISO-8859-1 [western european] and UTF-8, and and will _never_ work on hebrew text. In general I recommend to _never_ use these functions. If necessary use [`mb_convert_encoding()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding), specifying both destination _and_ source encodings. However your problem is still #1 and encoding problems are secondary to solving that.